# Classic asp query not sorting by username connecting to a Microsoft Access database

Tags: asp-classic

I am running across a strange occurrence using classic asp. I inherited an application which is written in classic asp connecting to a Microsoft Access Database. I am editing the code in Adobe Dreamweaver. In the table I am trying to query, it contains 2 fields: ID and username. The fields on the asp page include month, year, and the username. If I query the ID field, the query displays properly, and the username field is display by ID. However if I try to  order the query by username it will not display properly. Instead it doesn't display an username at all.

The classic asp code which works as follows when I want to order by the ID:

```
rstDATA.open "SELECT username FROM [c-names] order by ID", cnn, adLockReadOnly
```

The classic asp code which works is as follows when I want to order by the 
username which doesn't work:

```
rstDATA.open "SELECT username FROM [c-names] order by username", cnn, adLockReadOnly
```

The strange part is if I run a sql query within Microsoft Access it works:

```
SELECT [c-names].[username] FROM [c-names] ORDER BY [c-names].[username];
```

I tried to paste the code in the classic asp page but it didn't work either.

Does anyone know why it is not working? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are querying 2 fields as stated in your question.  Your select statement only includes username to display.  Are you copying the exact code to this post?  If not you may be missing username and id in your code.  In order to sort by a field, that field should be displayed.

Comment: this is not "strange part", that is how it should be.

Answer (score 1):

this is not "strange part", that is how it should be.

if you are using reserved word as field name, then you must take field name in brasket '[]'.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826763

> WORKAROUND
>
> To work arond this problem, do not use special characters.
> If you must use special characters in query expressions, enclose the
> special characters in brackets ([]). For example, if you want to use
> the greater than sign (>), use [>].